# Is it possible to Create a 'super' variable and then change it to a sub class type and be able to access the subclass methods

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

What I would like is to be able to create a variable with the superclass and then 'turn' it into the subclass later & be able to access the subClasses methods. It will always be defined to a subclass I just don't know which when defining.

```
class SuperClass {
  //superclass methods
}

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
  void subClass1method() {
    //do something
  }
}

class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
  void subClass2method() {
    //do something different
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    SuperClass a;

    if (*some reson to be SubClass1*) {
      a = new SubClass1();
      a.subClass1Method();     //this is undefined it says
      //a instanceof SubClass1 returns true which is what confused me
    } else {
      a = new SubClass2();
      a.subClass2Method();     //this is undefined it says
    }
  }
}
```

I am not asking why it does this but the correct way to work around it & get the results I want.

I have looked for duplicates but could have easily missed one so please let me know.

Comment: If you define your variable as `SuperClass a` then you can only call the methods of that `SuperClass` on `a` and there is no way around it. You can only create a (temporable) new variable through casting and access the Methods through that: `((SubClass1) a).subClass1Method();` but you will never be able to call `subClass1Method()` directly on `a` without changing the type from `SuperClass` to `SubClass1` first.

Comment: a SuperClass can be mapped to a SubClass, but you'll have to implement the mapping yourself

Comment: The usual method is to create a constructor in `SubClass` to create a new object from the old one: `public SubClass( SuperClass c ) ...`.  But as OGS said it is not possible to simply turn an super class into a sub class, you must do it manually.

Comment: There's a design pattern that says *"I have a large number of different subclasses and I want to call a variety of different methods on them but it's difficult to know which method."*  The solution is basically *"Jam all the methods into one subclass and let the object figure it out."*  C.f. [Composite Pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having access to the subClass code as in:

`SubClass1 b = new SubClass1();`
`a = b;`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you name both methods with the same name?

Comment: "Without access to the sub-class source code?" Almost certainly "no."  If you're dealing with a third party library, the only solution is to kick the library designers and tell them to design better code.  Or chose a library that better suits your needs.  With crazy effort using reflection or byte code weaving it might be possible, but that's likely brittle and not worth the effort.

Comment: No Roie Shlosberg I can't as I do not have access to the class's code

Comment: Jabob Thompson, are subClass1method and subClass2method mothods defined in SuperClass?

Comment: Ok thank you markspace it's for university and it's a class designed by the teacher so I can't 'kick' it but i will find a workaround for sure

Comment: no roie and i also can't access that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have control of the source then there's not too much you can do besides casting (or *possibly* using adapters). If `instanceof` and casting sound familiar from your lessons then that's probably what your prof is expecting.

Here are some of your options:

```
// to execute those subclass specific methods without casting..
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    SuperClass superClass;
    if (true /*some reson to be SubClass1*/) {
        SubClass1 subClass1 = new SubClass1();
        subClass1.subClass1Method();
        superClass = subClass1;
    } else {
        SubClass2 subClass2 = new SubClass2();
        subClass2.subClass2Method();
        superClass = subClass2;
    }
    // ... ...
}

// using instanceof and casting
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    SuperClass superClass;
    if (true /*some reson to be SubClass1*/) {
        superClass = new SubClass1();
    } else {
        superClass = new SubClass2();
    }

    // ... ... ...

    if(superClass instanceof SubClass1) {
        ((SubClass1) superClass).subClass1Method();
    } else if(superClass instanceof SubClass2) {
        ((SubClass2) superClass).subClass2Method();
    }
}
```

---

*Below is my recommendation to achieve this goal when you have control of the source..*

Rather than a new class for different behaviors you could just use composition to provide different behaviors to the one class. Note that this is especially convenient if you understand Functional Interfaces and Method References.

```
public class SuperClass {
    private MyBehavior behavior;

    public void setBehavior(MyBehavior behavior) { this.behavior = behavior; }

    public void doBehavior() { this.behavior.doBehavior(); }
}

public interface MyBehavior { public void doBehavior(); }

public class MyGoodBehavior implements MyBehavior {
    @Override public void doBehavior() { System.out.print("good behavior"); }
}

public class MyBadBehavior implements MyBehavior {
    @Override public void doBehavior() { System.out.print("bad behavior"); }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass a = new SuperClass();
    a.setBehavior(new MyBadBehavior());
    
    a.doBehavior();
}
```

Comment: this looks good but sadly I can't access the class source code. So it all has to be done in `void main`

Comment: Bleh, homework constraints :p Can't modify any of the classes? In that case it does sound like you'll need `instanceof` and casting to the subclasses to access their specific methods.

Comment: and how would one do that

Comment: @JacobThompson I've edited my answer to show you some of your options. Since this is for homework, please try to take the time to understand this concept rather than just copy-paste a solution. Best of luck in your studies.

Comment: thank you I will probably just have to change my entire thing because the only reason i wanted to this was to save 10 or so lines and having to add `if(superClass instanceof SubClass1) {
        ((SubClass1) superClass).subClass1Method();
    } else if(superClass instanceof SubClass2) {
        ((SubClass2) superClass).subClass2Method();
    }` will cost more lines than it would save. Either way i have accepted your answer as it covers all bases

Comment: @JacobThompson An advice from a seasoned developer: don't save lines. Lines are not a good metric. What you want is your program to be readable and quickly parseable by a fellow developer.

Comment: @xtratic +1 just because you show encapsulation. Nice :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
If you define "a" of class "SuperClass" you can only access "SuperClass" methods!
Eventually you could add abstract methods "subClass1method" and "subClass2method" to "SuperClass" and implement them in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `SuperClass a` you tell the compiler that you intend to store objects of type `SuperClass` in the variable `a`. It means that you can store subclasses of `SuperClass` as well, but the compiler only sees `a` as an object of type `SuperClass`, regardless if you are storing a sub type.

At runtime there's no check for this, if you manage to write code that calls methods from a subclass on `a`, they will be called. If `a` is not of that particular sub class and don't implement the called method, an exception would be thrown.

But how do you force the compiler to accept that `a` is of the subclass type? Casting. You cast `a` to the subclass, then you can access methods from subclass on `a`. If it´s not even possible to cast an object to a subclass, you get an error at compile time.

Change your `Main` class to the following and it should do what you want:

```
class Main {
  public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    SuperClass a;

    if (*some reson to be SubClass1*) {
      a = new SubClass1();
      ((SubClass1)a).subClass1Method();     // Casting 'a' as SubClass1
    } else {
      a = new SubClass2();
      ((SubClass2)a).subClass2Method();     // Casting 'a' as SubClass2
    }
  }
}
```

A few examples of when casting work and don't work at compile time and runtime:

```
class SuperClass { }

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass { }

class SubClass2 extends SuperClass { }

class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    SuperClass a;
    SubClass1 b;
    SubClass2 c;

    b = new SubClass1();
    a = b;  // autocast to SuperClass

    a = new SubClass1();
    b = a;  // Compile error
    b = (SubClass1) a;  // explicit cast

    c = new SubClass2();

    method(b);   // works
    method(c);   // compiles, but will throw exception at runtime inside method
  }

  private static void method(SuperClass object) {
    SubClass1 b = (SubClass1) object;  // allowed by compiler but will throw exception at runtime in the second call, method(c)
  }
}
```